# Pandas append row based on conditional sum in long form

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sum, pandas-groupby

So, I have some sample data as such:

```
import pandas as pd
objs = [
    {'location':'US', 'fruit':'apple', 'time':'night', 'value': 1},
    {'location':'US', 'fruit':'orange', 'time':'night', 'value': 3},
    {'location':'US', 'fruit':'banana', 'time':'night', 'value': 1},
    {'location':'EU', 'fruit':'apple', 'time':'night', 'value': 4},
    {'location':'EU', 'fruit':'orange', 'time':'night', 'value': 1},
    {'location':'EU', 'fruit':'banana', 'time':'night', 'value': 2},
    {'location':'US', 'fruit':'apple', 'time':'day', 'value': 5},
    {'location':'US', 'fruit':'orange', 'time':'day', 'value': 2},
    {'location':'US', 'fruit':'banana', 'time':'day', 'value': 3},
    {'location':'EU', 'fruit':'apple', 'time':'day', 'value': 6},
    {'location':'EU', 'fruit':'orange', 'time':'day', 'value': 2},
    {'location':'EU', 'fruit':'banana', 'time':'day', 'value': 1},
]
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(objs)
```

which gives a dataframe in long form like:

```
   location   fruit   time  value
0        US   apple  night      1
1        US  orange  night      3
2        US  banana  night      1
3        EU   apple  night      4
4        EU  orange  night      1
5        EU  banana  night      2
6        US   apple    day      5
7        US  orange    day      2
8        US  banana    day      3
9        EU   apple    day      6
10       EU  orange    day      2
11       EU  banana    day      1
```

---

I want to, for each pair/grouping of `location` and `time`, conditionally sum the `value` column based on the value in the `fruit` column.
Specifically:

I want to sum the `apple` and `orange` but NOT the `banana` rows for each grouping.

Resulting in the below dataframe, with the new rows as specified

```
   location      fruit   time  value
0        US      apple  night      1
1        US     orange  night      3
2        US     banana  night      1
3        US  NO_BANANA  night      4  <--
4        EU      apple  night      4
5        EU     orange  night      1
6        EU     banana  night      2
7        EU  NO_BANANA  night      5  <--
8        US      apple    day      5
9        US     orange    day      2
10       US     banana    day      3
11       US  NO_BANANA    day      7  <--
12       EU      apple    day      6
13       EU     orange    day      2
14       EU     banana    day      1
15       EU  NO_BANANA    day      8  <--
```

---

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the condition is the same for each group, just filter first then group by:

```
subdf = df[df['fruit']!='banana'].groupby(['location', 'time']).sum().reset_index()
subdf['fruit'] = 'NO_BANANA'
df = pd.concat([df, subdf]).sort_values(['time', 'location'], ascending = False).reset_index(drop=True)
```

```
location    fruit   time    value
0   US  apple   night   1
1   US  orange  night   3
2   US  banana  night   1
3   US  NO_BANANA   night   4
4   EU  apple   night   4
5   EU  orange  night   1
6   EU  banana  night   2
7   EU  NO_BANANA   night   5
8   US  apple   day 5
9   US  orange  day 2
10  US  banana  day 3
11  US  NO_BANANA   day 7
12  EU  apple   day 6
13  EU  orange  day 2
14  EU  banana  day 1
15  EU  NO_BANANA   day 8
```

Answer (score 2):

- create the group/aggregate you want, excluding **banana**
- `concat()` with original data
- sort / index as required

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""   location   fruit   time  value
0        US   apple  night      1
1        US  orange  night      3
2        US  banana  night      1
3        EU   apple  night      4
4        EU  orange  night      1
5        EU  banana  night      2
6        US   apple    day      5
7        US  orange    day      2
8        US  banana    day      3
9        EU   apple    day      6
10       EU  orange    day      2
11       EU  banana    day      1"""), sep="\s+")

df = (pd.concat([df, df.loc[df.fruit.ne("banana")].groupby(["location","time"],as_index=False).agg({"value":"sum"}).assign(fruit="NO_BANANA")])
 .sort_values(["time","location","fruit"], ascending=[0,0,1])
 .reset_index(drop=True)
)
```

#### output

|  | location | fruit | time | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | US | NO_BANANA | night | 4 |
| 1 | US | apple | night | 1 |
| 2 | US | banana | night | 1 |
| 3 | US | orange | night | 3 |
| 4 | EU | NO_BANANA | night | 5 |
| 5 | EU | apple | night | 4 |
| 6 | EU | banana | night | 2 |
| 7 | EU | orange | night | 1 |
| 8 | US | NO_BANANA | day | 7 |
| 9 | US | apple | day | 5 |
| 10 | US | banana | day | 3 |
| 11 | US | orange | day | 2 |
| 12 | EU | NO_BANANA | day | 8 |
| 13 | EU | apple | day | 6 |
| 14 | EU | banana | day | 1 |
| 15 | EU | orange | day | 2 |

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to create a pivot_table

```py
df = df.pivot_table(index=['location', 'time', 'fruit'],
                    values=['value']).unstack()
```

```py
               value              
fruit          apple banana orange
location time                     
EU       day       6      1      2
         night     4      2      1
US       day       5      3      2
         night     1      1      3
```

Filter fruits column-wise based on blacklist:

```py
# Mask Fruits To Keep/Exclude
fruits_blacklist = ['banana']
cm = np.where(df.columns.get_level_values(1).isin(fruits_blacklist), False, True)
```

Then sum row-wise the filtered columns:

```py
df[('value', 'NO_BANANA')] = df.loc[:, cm].apply(np.sum, axis=1)
```

---

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


# blacklist
fruits_blacklist = ['banana']

# Create Pivot Table
df = df.pivot_table(index=['location', 'time', 'fruit'],
                    values=['value']).unstack()

# Mask Fruits To Keep/Exclude
cm = np.where(df.columns.get_level_values(1).isin(fruits_blacklist), False, True)
# Sum Row-wise
df[('value', 'NO_BANANA')] = df.loc[:, cm].apply(np.sum, axis=1)
# Stack and Reset Index
df = df.stack('fruit') \
    .sort_values(["time", "location"],
                 ascending=False) \
    .reset_index()

# For Display
print(df.to_string())
```

Output:

```
   location   time      fruit  value
0        US  night      apple      1
1        US  night     banana      1
2        US  night     orange      3
3        US  night  NO_BANANA      4
4        EU  night      apple      4
5        EU  night     banana      2
6        EU  night     orange      1
7        EU  night  NO_BANANA      5
8        US    day      apple      5
9        US    day     banana      3
10       US    day     orange      2
11       US    day  NO_BANANA      7
12       EU    day      apple      6
13       EU    day     banana      1
14       EU    day     orange      2
15       EU    day  NO_BANANA      8
```